# How to work with C# projects in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm creating a C# multiple project solution in Visual Studio Code.

I created using dotnet cli with the fallowing commands:

```
# create new solution 
dotnet new sln

# create new projects
dotnet new webapi -o api
dotnet new mstest -o tests
dotnet new console -o console

# add projects to solution
dotnet sln add api
dotnet sln add tests
dotnet sln add console

# compile projects
dotnet run build
```

At the build command, the dotnet compiles the three projects.

All three projects was added to the solution

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
Project("{...}") = "api", "api\api.csproj", "{...}"
EndProject
Project("{...}") = "console", "console\console.csproj", "{...}"
EndProject
Project("{...}") = "tests", "tests\tests.csproj", "{...}"
EndProject
```

Based on the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp), I should be able to choose the loaded projects by clicking on the status bar:

[image: Documentation project]

It shows that there is one project

However I'm only able to see my solution project.

[image: my project]
[image: project results]

What am I missing? What should iI do in order to work with several projects in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: VS Code is pretty light weight.  You should be able to open the .cs files, or open it all as a folder, but it's not going to give you all the intellisense you want.  Have you tried using VS 2017 Community instead?  If that's not possible, you may just want to open the folder above all of the project directories.

Comment: I agree with you. My concern is that the official documentation tells us that it's possible. But I was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Did you install the c# support as suggested here?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: Yes. O Dos @nixkuroi

Comment: What you see is by design I think. Only if you have multiple .sln files, the list would have more items. The term "solutions" and "projects" are interchangeable and usually mix, so when the documentation says "projects", it can mean "solutions".

Comment: @LexLi. You're right. I tried out creating a new solution, them it appears on the list.